# Sqlsrv PHP driver and UTF-8 encoding issue with error messages

Tags: php, sql-server, utf-8

I'm using the Microsoft sqlsrv driver with UTF-8 encoding (by passing CharacterSet 'UTF-8' to sqlsrv_connect). This works fine for the actual data stored in the database but I found a problem with non-English text returned by sqlsrv_errors. When using a different language for SQL Server (e.g., `SET LANGUAGE German`), I found that the returned error messages are not UTF-8 encoded. This is what sqlsrv_errors() returned for a 8152 error:

```
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Zeichenfolgen- oder Bin?rdaten w?rden abgeschnitten.
```

And as hex (only the two invalid words):

```
B i n ? r d a t e n  w ? r d e n
42696e8472646174656e 77817264656e
```

So, the problematic characters are encoded as 84 (actually U+00E4) and 81 (actually U+00FC) which I can't relate to any encoding. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Tobias

Comment: I don't know sqlsrv well, but probably you need to configure the server and tell which encoding the german language is. It looks like that the server has a problem to re-encode strings in german language to your requested UTF-8 client character set.

Comment: We have the same kind of issue, but on our side instead of getting `sqlsrv_errors()` we call `sqlsrv_configure('WarningsReturnAsErrors', 0);`before. After that, we perform a `BACKUP` followed by SELECT in the same statement. The BACKUP command actually sends warnings (it outputs messages in the console in SSMS). We don't want these warnings the be treated as errors, but the side effect is that those messages are missinterpreted if we connect using CharacterSet UTF-8 and crashing PHP when calling `sqlsrv_next_result`, which is also bad

Comment: Hi @MaxiWheat, this is an old thread but i also have the same issue now. i am already searching for this issue for 5 days now :s Could you tell me how did you solve this issue?? It would be very helpfull. Thanks